# Connecting multiple cities on a map using MapQuest route API

Tags: python, api, mapping, mapquest

I am working on any optimal vehicle routing problem.
I want to start map routing on the road starting from
one city A 
to city B to City C
 to city D 
back to city A

Based on lat/lng of these cities

I have the cities already worked out just want to display it on map-quest map?

This is sound as it is fundamental what mapping solution will offer out of the box but I am had googled this for days now with no particular solution

Can somebody point out the right direction to go?

I am using MapQuest.

Comment: like this? https://www.mapquest.com/directions/list/1/us/new-york/john-f-kennedy-international-airport-jfk-371814002/to/us/dc/washington/to/us/il/chicago/to/us/ny/new-york

Comment: yes!!!! how do i make that work with my data set ????????

Comment: do you have latitude/longitude with your data?

Comment: yes i do or any thing that will work

Answer (score 0):

Well for me it is not clear what you want to achieve exactly. Here are two options.
The first one will get you your routing information as a json or xml (see mapquest api docs) to do further processing.
The second option is just an Example to show your routing using the mapQuest/directions api in a hacky way.

This will get you a json response with your routing information:

```
from RouteOptions import RouteOptions
from RouteService import RouteService

options = RouteOptions()
service = RouteService('YOUR_MAPQUEST_DEVELOPER_API_KEY')

multi_location_list = ['Lancaster, PA', 'State College, PA', 'York, PA']
multiDirRoute = service.directions(locations=multi_location_list, options=options)
```

More information can be found here: 
https://github.com/MapQuest/directions-api-python-client
https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/directions-api/

If you want to see your route with https://mapQuest.com/directions you could hack yourself the url string and open it with the browser.

Example string:

```
https://www.mapquest.com/directions/from/near-33.94,-118.13/to/us/il/chicago/to/us/dc/washington/to/us/ny/new-york
```

So you could insert the coordinates .../from/near...,..../to/near...,.../to/near...,...

This will open your browser and display the route.

```
import webbrowser

website = "https://www.mapquest.com/directions/from/near-33.94,-118.13/to/us/il/chicago/to/us/dc/washington/to/us/ny/new-york"
webbrowser.open_new(website)
```